# Cliente de Ionic a la API con NodeJS

Tags: angularjs, nodejs, ionic, api

Tengo un problema, es una *API* con *NodeJS* y el cliente con *Ionic* (código disponible [aquí](http://paste.ofcode.org/396BKFNYJeedYuSKrR5zvYS) también).

```
// SERVICES.JS
angular.module('app.services', [])

.factory('loginService', function($http){
    return{
        print: function() {
            return $http.get('http://EXTERNALURL:3000/print').then(function(res) {
                return res.data;
            })
        },
        login: function(post) {
            return $http({
                url: 'http://EXTERNALURL:3000/login',
                method: 'POST',
                data: post,
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
            }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log(data);
            }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log(status);
            });
        }
    }
})
// ROUTES.JS en servidor externo 
app.post('/login', function(req, res){
    console.log(req.body)
    AM.manualLogin(req.body['user'], req.body['pass'], function(e, o){
        if (!o){
            res.status(400).send(e);
        }   else{
            req.session.user = o;
            if (req.body['remember-me'] == 'true'){
                res.cookie('user', o.user, { maxAge: 900000 });
                res.cookie('pass', o.pass, { maxAge: 900000 });
            }
            res.status(200).send(o);
        }
    });
});
```

El Problema es que al enviar los datos desde postman en el servidor por la línea `console.log(req.body)` me los muestra así:

```
{"user":"mceliz@enlaceit.com.ar","pass":"Seighei7"}
```

Que es la forma correcta, pero al enviarlos desde *Ionic* con el cliente que arme en **services.js** lo muestra así:

```
{ '{"user":"mceliz@enlaceit.com.ar","pass":"Seighei7"}': '' }
```

Comment: He editado tu pregunta (espera a que sea confirmada para ver los cambios). Trata de no utilizar lenguaje vulgar aunque estemos entre camaradas ;).

Comment: ¿En dónde armas la data a enviar, es decir, `post`? ¿Podrías pone ese trozo de código?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema se soluciono gracias a `transformRequest` como opcion en mi `$http request`

Comment: Por favor, brinda más información sobre esto para que se considere una respuesta de calidad.